# How can I enable zoom on Android?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, responsive-design, meta-tags

That's right, I want to *enable* zooming rather than *disabling* it.

I have created a responsive website and all is looking good. However for some reason you can't pinch-zoom in Chrome on a Nexus 7 (running Android 4.2.2).

This is my meta tag that makes sure it shows the site with the right CSS for the screen size:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Nowhere here do I say the user can't zoom. As I say, the site is responsive so there is no reason for the user to need to zoom, however if a user wants to zoom I don't want to stop them. There is no problem on the iPhone, the user can zoom if they want to. But on Android they can't. I have tried adding `user-scalable=yes` and `user-scalable=1` but this makes no difference.

The only thing that works is removing that meta tag but then the site renders itself as if it's being displayed on a large screen so it is no longer responsive.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Well this is not an answer but more of a comment - Chrome for Android has a way for us to force zoom -  Open up the browser's main settings and tap "Accessibility," then check the option called Force enable zoom. This way if you dont find a good answer that suits your requirements here, add this as a comment on your page

Comment: There's also [this SO answer on how to force-zoom](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/66198/193765). My android life would be much worse without. (looking closer at things, making better screenshots, easier form-filling on poorly designed sites...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@David Lee's comment on top is correct: It seems more of a Nexus 7 thing than a Chrome problem.  Google has had a lot of complaints regarding pinch-to-zoom wrt Nexus 7 and there is [speculation](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Jelly-Bean-already-works-around-Apples-pinch-to-zoom-patent_id33913) that they are trying to work around Apple's pinch to zoom patent.

From what I know just using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

should work.

I've looked at http://m.skyscanner.com/ as an example and it works on other devices with chrome and other browsers like Dolphin HD. And all that site has is the viewport code from above.

Chrome for Android has a way for us to force zoom - Open up the browser's main settings and tap "Accessibility," then check the option called Force enable zoom and see if this works in Nexus 7(I dont have that device so cant test it)

Answer (score 6):

What version of Android? Android 2.2 doesn't support the viewport meta-tag, if your version is between 2.3.x and 4.x try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, user-scalable=yes" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it says Android 4.2.2 so that can't be the issue. Also I have tried `user-scalable=yes` but I wrote `user-scalable=true` in my question so apologies for that. I have now edited my question.

Comment: I have been checking this out, and it seems there is a issue with the zoom option on chrome in the Nexus 7, not sure if its true though, also i tested on a SG2 and it works normal, i think what you can do is check another site that has the zoom option and check the viewport tag there or other configuration that maybe its enabling it, if you get results please post here, i develop responsive websites too and it would be helpful to know, i will try to dig more on it.

Answer (score 2):

use this hope it will help:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,width=device-width,height=device-height,target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=yes" />
```

Comment: As far as I can tell setting a minimum and maximum scale as 1 would disable user scaling, would it not?

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter below: **user-scalable** = 1:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1" />
```